# Multiplier algebra of $A \otimes \mathcal{K}$

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

If $A$ is unital C$^*$-algebra, is it true that the multiplier algebra of $A \otimes \mathcal{K} $ is $ A \otimes \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$? Where $\mathcal{K}$ is  C$^*$-algebra of compact operators on the Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

Answer (score 10):

The fact stated in the answer by vap is proven in the paper "[Multipliers of C*-algebras](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022123673900360)" by Akemann, Pedersen and Tomiyama (see Theorem 3.3, I guess). Moreover, they prove in Theorem 3.8 that multiplier algebras are not very well behaved with respect to minimal tensor products:

> Let $A$ and $B$ be $C^*$-algebras and assume that $B$ has a countable
>   approximate unit, but no unit (think of $\mathcal{K}$ here in your
>   case) and that $A$ is infinite dimensional. Then
>   $$ 
> M(A) \otimes M(B) \subsetneq M(A \otimes B) 
> $$ 
>   where the tensor product is the minimal one.

So, in particular, for any *infinite dimensional* unital $C^*$-algebra $A$, the tensor product $A \otimes \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ is always a proper subalgebra of $M(A \otimes \mathcal{K})$.

Answer (score 8):

If $A=C_0(X)$ and $B$ is a $C^\ast$-algebra then $M(A\otimes B)$ is the set of strictly continuous functions $\beta X\to M(B)$, where $\beta$ stands for Stone-Čech compactification.

If you take $X$ to be compact and $B=\mathcal{K}$ then we are in your setting.

But $C(X)\otimes\mathcal{B(H)}$ is the set of norm-continuos functions $\beta X=X\to\mathcal{B(H)}$. The strict topology is the $\sigma$-strong-$^\ast$ topology on $\mathcal{B(H)}$, which is different form the norm topology. This should answer your question in the negative.

Comment: What space $X$ do you have in mind? (It must be infinite, of course.)

Comment: The one-point compactification of the natural numbers should work. We can use this space to index a sequence converging in the strict topology of bounded operators, but not converging in norm.

Comment: For future reference, as pointed out in the comments of https://mathoverflow.net/questions/375906 this is not true.  $M(A\otimes B)$ may be identified with the space of strictly continuous, bounded functions $X\rightarrow M(B)$, and not from $\beta X$.

Comment: @MatthewDaws Thanks. The error probably stems from the universal property of the Stone-Čech compactification: one would like to upgrade bounded functions on $X$ to continuous functions on the compactification. But this only works if the bounded sets in $M(B)$ are compact in the strict topology, which I think can fail even when $B$ is commutative.